# Getting "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" from seaborn boxplot of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a `pandas` dataframe

[image]

and I'm trying to make `seaborn` boxplots:

```
sns.boxplot(data=df_filtered[df_filtered['Class'] == 1].drop(['Plot', 'Class'], axis=1))
```

but it returns

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The thing is, I have used exactly the same command on different data and it works fine. I have produced many boxplots this way. Also, the `matplotlib` version works:

```
plt.boxplot(x=df_filtered[df_filtered['Class'] == 1].drop(['Plot', 'Class'], axis=1))
```

[image]

Obviously I could just use the `matplotlib` command but then I have to redo all previous plots, which is not good, and I'd like to know what's going wrong anyway. Could this be a bug, or am I missing something?

Edit: Here is the full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7004\328781716.py in ?()
     11 df_filtered_sorted = df_filtered.sort_values(by='Class')
     12 
---> 13 class_labels = df_filtered_sorted['Class'].unique()
     14 n_rows = len(class_labels) // 2 + len(class_labels) % 2
     15 n_cols = 2
     16 

~\miniconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in ?(data, x, y, hue, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth, whis, ax, **kwargs)
   2227     dodge=True, fliersize=5, linewidth=None, whis=1.5, ax=None,
   2228     **kwargs
   2229 ):
   2230 
-> 2231     plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
   2232                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
   2233                           width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)
   2234 

~\miniconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in ?(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)
    781     def __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
    782                  orient, color, palette, saturation,
    783                  width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth):
    784 
--> 785         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
    786         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
    787 
    788         self.dodge = dodge

~\miniconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in ?(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    458                 if order is None:
    459                     order = []
    460                     # Reduce to just numeric columns
    461                     for col in data:
--> 462                         if variable_type(data[col]) == "numeric":
    463                             order.append(col)
    464                 plot_data = data[order]
    465                 group_names = order

~\miniconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_oldcore.py in ?(vector, boolean_type)
   1498     if pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(vector):
   1499         return VariableType("categorical")
   1500 
   1501     # Special-case all-na data, which is always "numeric"
-> 1502     if pd.isna(vector).all():
   1503         return VariableType("numeric")
   1504 
   1505     # Special-case binary/boolean data, allow caller to determine

~\miniconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ?(self)
   1517     @final
   1518     def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1519         raise ValueError(
   1520             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1521             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1522         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible, so it is difficult to answer.

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question. (2) Try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Agreed. It seems to be specific to the dataframe, which is weird. I will post the data. Edit: Thanks for heads up about full error. The MRE is what I'm struggling with, again because it appears to be specific to the data. I'll try to improve it.

Comment: I realise this question is, technically, "caused by a typo", but the issue is that seaborn produces an error when two columns have the same name, whereas matplotlib and pandas just keep working. Also, the error produced by the duplicate names is not really helpful. I see where it's coming from now, but I don't think this is intended behaviour.

Comment: At the end of the day if you wish to use seaborn here you will have to avoid duplicate column names (you may want to avoid duplicate columns names generally, for lots of reasons). If you think seaborn should work like matplotlib here open an issue with seaborn. I don't know if "caused by a typo" is a good description of the problem - duplicate columns names are not typos. Rather the cause of the error was correctly identified and a solution provided to get seaborn working for you. So I don't see closing this as appropriate. Oh well. This is life at stack overflow.

Comment: Note for future questions - providing a reproducible example will help you avoid getting questions downvoted! Don't post an image of your dataframe - post code that creates the dataframe, so others can reproduce the problem. Any question with code or data like this posted as an image is likely to be downvoted quickly. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: That's entirely fair enough. I had it in my head that it was the entire dataframe that was causing the issue and the dataframe is large, hence my unwillingness to post it originally. In retrospect I could have posted the header as code and ended up achieving the same thing. Noted and thanks for the advice.

Comment: The error message *"The Truth value of a Series is ambiguous..."* is telling you that the LHS of your comparison `variable_type(data[col]) == "numeric"` is actually a series (i.e. multiple values), not just a single value, as your code expects. And in turn the cause for that is that `data[col]` is non-unique, i.e. `col` is duplicated. If you had posted reproducible data (instead of an image of data, like people asked you above), it would have gotten diagnosed instantly.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I get that now about the image. Totally my fault.

Comment: Okay. Please take a quick skim of [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks. Will do. So I've got an MRE ready to go. I've spent some time trying to isolate the problem and have found that my dataframe, even when I cut it down to only a few lines, produces the error with seaborn, but a dummy dataframe with duplicate columns works fine. maplotlib also handles my data with duplicate column names fine. Is it worth it give the question a heavy edit, or just do better next time?

Comment: If you can edit this question to post reproducible data for `df_filtered`, such that the rest of us can run it and replicate the error, then the question can be reopened. (We don't need all your data, you can strip down your dataframe to a few sample columns, or seeded-random data. As long as that still reproduces the error).

Comment: In checking my MRE I found that matplotlib produces the plot because it ignores the column names, while seaborn uses them (hence the error), and my dummy data was working because pandas either ignores duplicate column names (in the case of direct df creation) or renames them (when loading from csv). I finally fully understand what's going on and the solution is trivial. I'll leave the question closed. Thanks for all the help and sorry for the hassle, I've learned a lot about pandas and posting to SO.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to paste the data when I saw that two of the columns in the dataframe have the same name. When I change the name of the last column, removing the duplication, it works.

[image]

I don't know if anything needs to be done with this information. Thanks all for the help.